# Partial differential equations, solving for coefficients with "bounded" condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem: Show the eigenvalue problem has no negative eigenvalues 
$-y(\rho)-\frac{2}{\rho} y'(\rho)=\lambda y(\rho)$ 
$y(0)$ bounded, $y(\pi)=0$

  
Solution: 
Making the transformation 
 $Y = \rho y$ we get $−Y=-\lambda Y$.
If $\lambda = −k^{2}$, then 
$Y = a \sinh(k\rho) + b \cosh (k\rho)$ 
or 
$y = \frac{1}{\rho}a \sinh(k\rho) + b \cosh (k\rho)$ 
For boundedness at $\rho = 0$ we set $b = 0$. Then $y(\pi) = 0$ forces $\sinh kπ = 0$. Thus
$k = 0$. Consequently, there are no negative eigenvalues.

My question is, I do not understand why we set $b = 0$ for boundedness? Why is $\cosh(k\rho)$ unbounded at $y(0)$?

Comment: Could you type out the content in the image?

Comment: @LouisPan Yes certainly!

Comment: thanks. you missed the parentheses for your final expression of $y$. Also, in the first equation, the first terms should be $y''$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$
y(\rho)=\frac1\rho(a\sinh(k\rho)+b\cosh(k\rho))
$$
and the limit
$\displaystyle
\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{\sinh(k\rho)}{\rho}=\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{e^{k\rho}-e^{-k\rho}}{2\rho}
$ exists. But if $b\ne 0$, the term $\frac{b\cosh(k\rho)}{\rho}$ would blow up as $\rho\to 0$.

It is not that $\cosh(k\rho)$ is unbounded at $\rho=0$ but that $\cosh(k\rho)/\rho$ is unbounded near $\rho=0$.